# What specifically about double-checked locking fails without volatile in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr, volatile, memory-model

All around the 'net there's advice against doing this in C#:

```
readonly object _lock = new object();
string _instance = null;
 
public string Instance {
    get {
        if (_instance == null) {
            lock (_lock) {
                if (_instance == null) _instance = GetName();
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Everywhere says you need to *at least* mark `_instance` as `volatile` to make this thread-safe (or just use `Lazy<T>`, but that's besides-the-point).

However, I've never really understood *why* this is. I've never been able to actually replicate a degenerate behaviour, and although that doesn't prove anything, in my head I see the following:

- The `lock` statement compiles down to `Monitor.Enter()`/`Monitor.Exit()` calls [which themselves emit full memory barriers](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility), meaning reads/writes can not cross the `lock()` boundary
- Because the second check and write to `_instance` is inside the lock, only one thread can write to `_instance` at a time (and invoke `GetName()`)
- Because `Monitor.Exit()` emits a full fence, by the time the `_lock` is 'marked' as open for any other thread to acquire it, `_instance` *must* have been written from their point-of-view, regardless of whether it is marked as `volatile` or not
- And furthermore, [I actually got Microsoft to clarify](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5206) that making a field `volatile` only acts as a shorthand for wrapping writes/reads to it in `Volatile.Read()`/`Volatile.Write()` and does nothing to "ensure immediacy/up-to-date values", whatever that would even mean.

The only problem I can maybe think of is premature publication of a constructed object (if `GetName()` was instead creating a new object); is that the issue? But even then, I'm not sure if that's valid in C#, and I don't see how making `_instance` `volatile` would help anyway.

Comment: why the downvote?  seems like a good question.

Comment: Hi yes, I'm actually just reading through that. For some reason it didn't show me that as a related item until I submitted the question- I'll vote to close it myself as duplicate in a few minutes if it does answer my question.

Edit: Voted, please close! Thanks :)

Comment: There are a bunch of historical duplicates and a wealth of information on the topic. In short this should be fine in a lot of cases, however there are cases platforms environments where its not so clear cut. If you want this to be bullet-proof you know the answer